# Search friends by location on Facebook

Tags: facebook, geo-location

I'm looking for a browser extension, a user script, a desktop program or anything else that would allow me to search friends by location on Facebook (e.g. looking for which of my friends live in or close to city X).

Comment: There is a community discussion on this https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10152334105290313

Comment: Check this thread [search for friends in a specific city](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=871110156249603).

Answer (score 1):

## Using [Graph Search](http://search.fb.com/)

[image]

The search above will bring up all your friends who live somewhere near London.